# Como fazer a importação de um arquivo .sql para um banco do android?

Tags: java, android

Tenho um arquivo .sql que contém vários inserts e eu precisava que minha aplicação lesse esse arquivo e fizesse esses inserts, em uma tabela que eu tenho criada. Existe algum jeito ?

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199138/android-how-to-exec-a-sql-file-in-sqlitedatabase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que uma alternativa é vc importar esse arquivo no BD original (mysql, postgres...) e exportar em planilha. Depois disso, importar essa planilha no SGDB do android.